# What's like OSX's pbcopy for Linux

Tags: linux, macos

In a terminal in OSX I can pipe output to pbcopy and then go into a web browser and paste it. I tried this in Linux with xcopy but when I switch to the browser it just overwrites the clipboard with with whatever was in it the last time the browser was used. What works like pbcopy in Linux?

Comment: ...and for those that don't know what pbcopy is, here's the man page http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html

Comment: A tool that can be helpful with this is [ClipIt](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt) (and similar clipboard managers). Not only it plays nicely in the terminal, it also preserves the clipboard history. Quite useful.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

If you have desktop version of Linux (X) installed you may try `xsel` in this way:

```
alias pbcopy='xsel --clipboard --input'
alias pbpaste='xsel --clipboard --output'
```

or with `xclip`:

```
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
```

Now you can use them:

```
echo 'go to my clipboard' | pbcopy
```

When I don't have X I use GNU Screen functionality to copy between open shells in a session using keyboard.

Copy:

- <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- go to wanted position *
- <kbd>Space</kbd> (to begin selecting)
- press <kbd>k</kbd> to go forward mark text
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Paste:

- <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

* movements are done with vim like key bindings (<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> & <kbd>m</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the information I wanted.  Tho now I wonder if there is a way I could make Screen let me use Emacs commands to select the area I want to copy...

Comment: xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: I solved the "Can't open display" problem on Windows by installing [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) and setting DISPLAY=:0

Comment: For tmux users, it's more like `Ctrl-b, [ -> go to position -> Space -> select texts -> Enter` and paste by `Ctrl-b, ]`

Comment: Whenever possible—if this is something permanent you want, of course—rather than _complicating_ your namespace with aliasing in your profile, it's going to be better to create a basic script for this in `/bin/`. **Especially if you share your profile between macOS and linux machines.**

Comment: how to install xsel

Comment: So good, also `apt install xclip` too

Answer (score 11):

Put a script like this called pbcopy in your bin folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
xclip -i -sel c -f |xclip -i -sel p
```

This will put STDIN in both your selection buffer and clipboard:

```
echo Hello world |pbcopy
```

Comment: Why would the `cat` be needed? Won't it just redirect stdin to stdout in this case thus useless cat abuse or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right it does seem like useless cat abuse :-)

Comment: if you're (like me) wondering about where is the mysterious "useless cat", it has been removed by the edit. NTS: in case of confusing comments, check the history ^^'

Comment: How do you paste the contents after using this? Just using `xclip -o` ? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @n1k31t4 What I did was make an equivalent script using `xclip -sel c -o` for a script at `/bin/pbpaste`.

Answer (score 8):

This answer refers to the Linux Subsystem for Windows.

Short answer: use `clip.exe` as if it were `pbcopy` in order to put something on the Windows clipboard. It's magic. Example `echo "Hello Windows" | clip.exe` in your bash or Ubuntu bash terminal, and then `ctrl-v' in a Windows program.

More context:

In [a comment above](https://superuser.com/a/288333/379196) I mentioned that, when using Xming on Windows to enable this functionality, it is necessary to set a DISPLAY variable (`export DISPLAY=:0`, in many cases) before the `xsel` and `xclip` solutions work. Infuriatingly, this solution works in an unreliable, stochastic way -- when pasting from Linux to Windows, pressing `ctrl-v` between one and ten times causes the clipboard to be pasted (one time) (this is on my Windows 10 Surface Book 2). Don't waste your time, use `clip.exe`.

NOTE: Don't forget the `.exe`. Otherwise Ubuntu bash will suggest that you install the Linux package `geomview`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the solutions of @Erik and @xpixelz; these two scripts should work on both platforms:

pbcopy:

```
#!/bin/bash
__IS_MAC=${__IS_MAC:-$(test $(uname -s) == "Darwin" && echo 'true')}
if [ -n "${__IS_MAC}" ]; then
  cat | /usr/bin/pbcopy
else
  # copy to selection buffer AND clipboard
  cat | xclip -i -sel c -f | xclip -i -sel p
fi
```

pbpaste:

```
#!/bin/bash
__IS_MAC=${__IS_MAC:-$(test $(uname -s) == "Darwin" && echo 'true')}
if [ -n "${__IS_MAC}" ]; then
  /usr/bin/pbpaste
else
  xclip -selection clipboard -o
fi
```

Comment: But why would you even have this script on OS X where it's a part of the native userland?

Comment: * as a reference for similar functionality, * cross-platform dotfiles: https://github.com/westurner/dotfiles/blob/develop/scripts/pbcopy

Comment: Still cat abuse and why not check if xclip exist instead and assign an alias if it does? Or check if the pbpaste binary exist would also be an option. Checking the uname seems like an odd approach to the problem.

Comment: @Hultner "Checking the uname seems like an odd approach to the problem" You could also check for binaries, preferentially, in order, by exception with a ``${a:-${b:-${c:+${d}}}}`` and some  ``type -P``/ ``has`` variable assignments and /bin/test execs.

Answer (score 5):

In WSL2, you have `clipcopy` and `clippaste` which are equivalent to `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.

Comment: exactly what I needed thanks!